# what's the meaning of "groping for political relevance"

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Blamed for a painful recession at home, hounded by Washington do
>   deploy thousands of combat troops to Iraq and unable to resolve North
>   Korea's pressing nuclear problem, President Roh is **groping for
>   political relevance**.

what's the meaning of "groping for political relevance"?

I know 'groping' for means 'seeking for or looking for', but what is political relevance? Is it political insight or political ability?

Comment: If you're still not sure about the phrase after looking up *relevance* in a dictionary, post what you still find confusing and we'll try and answer.

Comment: @Graham Nicol I looked up relevance in a dictionary(Something's relevance to a situation or person is its importance or significance in that situation or to that person), and I still have no clue. looking for political importance? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

President Roh has been an ineffective political leader, not being able to solve pressing problems. As such he is no longer of much value to his country and its government. He is *groping for political relevance*: **looking for something that will make him valuable within the politics of his country**.